# ListView GridView Handle ColumnsReorder

Tags: wpf, gridview

How to handle/persists columns reorder?  Don't need to change it.  Need to persist it so when the user brings up the GridView again can present the columns in order they last defined.

```
 <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are not going to find a StoreColumnOrder="True" setting. You will have to code this up yourself. And to persist you have to store the order somewhere on disk, like a settings file.

Create a new object that inherits from your GridView (or you could create a UserControl as well) that adds one function to the onloaded event and one function to the onclose event. The onloaded function would look for a settings file and if it was there, reorder the columns. The onclose function createst the settings file if reordering has occurred.

Comment: I suspect your answer is correct I just don't know what add function to event means.  I know what inherit means.

Comment: Ok...I wrote a sample project for doing this.
http://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/04/10/saving-the-gridview-column-order-in-wpf/

Comment: Impressive.   I learned a few tricks from the code sample.   Thanks

Comment: See this (slightly old) article for _a_ solution: http://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/04/10/saving-the-gridview-column-order-in-wpf/ basically, declare some helper clases to gather the information you want to save, mark them as Serializable, use an XmlSerializer to punch them in and out of a convenient file.