# Reordering columns in DataTable via a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and have enabled the AllowUserToOrderColumns property so that the user can reorder the columns using drag and drop. I've created a handler for the ColumnDisplayIndexChanged event. The DataGridView is bound to a DataTable. I would like to reorder the columns in the DataTable when the user reorders that columns in the DataGridView.

This is what I've got so far:

```
private void dataGridView_Main_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if(!_isDatabinding)
    {
        if(_data.Columns[columnName].Ordinal != e.Column.DisplayIndex)
        {
            _data.Columns[e.Column.DataPropertyName].SetOrdinal(e.Column.DisplayIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this causes the following exception:

"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

I realised that this was happening because calling the SetOrdinal method was causing the event handler to be called again because the DataTable is bound to the DataGridView. So I changed it to the following:

```
private void dataGridView_Main_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if(!_isDatabinding && !_isChangingColumnOrder)
    {
        if(_data.Columns[columnName].Ordinal != e.Column.DisplayIndex)
        {
            _isChangingColumnOrder = true;
            _data.Columns[e.Column.DataPropertyName].SetOrdinal(e.Column.DisplayIndex);
            _isChangingColumnOrder = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This now throws a NullReferenceException within the DataGridViewColumn::DisplayIndex property setter. Here's the callstack:

```
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn.DisplayIndex.set(int value) + 0xc5 bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.EndColumnRelocation(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.HitTestInfo hti) + 0x27f bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) + 0x3a6 bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons button, int clicks) + 0x48b bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0xe14 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x134 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 514, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x14c bytes
```

I'm not sure what's causing this exception.

I've also tried setting the DataGridView's DataSource property to null in the event handler before I call SetOrdinal, then rebinding it at the end of the method. To try and avoid issues with the DataTable being bound to the DataGridView when reordering. But that still throws the same NullReferenceException. This probably wouldn't be ideal anyway, as the handler is called once for each affected column (ie. always more than once), and there doesn't seem to be any events I can handle to tell me when the column reordering has started and finished.

The only way I can get this to work at all is by doing the following (note the copy):

```
private void dataGridView_Main_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if(!_isDatabinding)
    {
        if(_data.Columns[columnName].Ordinal != e.Column.DisplayIndex)
        {
            var newData = _data.Copy();
            newData.Columns[e.Column.DataPropertyName].SetOrdinal(e.Column.DisplayIndex);
            _data = newData;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really want to have to do this copy though, as the data could potentially be quite large.

Is there any way I can do this without the copy?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the event handler temporarily before you set the ordinal and add it again afterwards?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I hadn't, but I've just tried it now and it still throws the same NullReferenceException unfortunately. Good thinking though! :)

Comment: Can you just wait until close?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098627/listview-gridview-handle-columnsreorder

Comment: @Blam Yes, I could probably wait until I save the file and the just take the DGVs DisplayIndex into account without physically reordering the DataTable columns. This is probably what I'll resort to if there's not a simple way to handle what I was trying to do. I'd ideally like to keep the DVG and DT in sync though. If it means a DT copy, it's not worth it though.

Answer (score 0):

Rebinding datagridview to datatable

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
    {
   dt.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText);    
    }

   foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
   {
     DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
    foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
     {
      dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
     }
    dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
   }
```

Comment: Iterating through every single cell isn't quite what I had in mind ;) If I was happy doing any form of copy, then I'd use the last code snippet that I put in my question. I just want to be able to set the DataTable's columns' ordinal. I'll probably end up doing what @Blam suggested and just using the sort order at "file save time".

Comment: DataColumn Col1 = dt.Columns.Add("Remove",System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
                Col1.SetOrdinal(0);